# Change default language in the google chrome translator bar

Tags: google-chrome, translation

I am italian, so I have Google Chrome in Italian.

When I browse the web in languages that I don't know, I find very useful the auto-translation bar of google chrome.

The problem is that it translates the language to english and then to italian. Double automatic translation = unintelligible text.

There is a way to force translation to english, and not my language?

Answer (score 3):

Don't think it's possible, but a quite good workaround is to install the offical extension called [Google Translate](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/aapbdbdomjkkjkaonfhkkikfgjllcleb). It will add a button in the rightmost corner which will translate the current page. If you then right-click this button and choose 'Options', you can set your default translating language.

Comment: Nice! But it overlaps with the default chrome translator

Answer (score 2):

Open a new tab in chrome and go to:

chrome://translate-internals

You will be able to manage it from there.

Comment: On chrome 30, it just contains informative text, there are no settings.

Answer (score 1):

1. right click the web page, and click `Translate to XXX`
   [image: step 1]
2. Wait, or double click the icon
   [image: step 2]
3. The popover is shown, click the `Options`
   [image: step 3]
4. Select your language, and translate
   [image: step 4]

Answer (score -1):

Try right click anywhere on the page and choose "Translate to English"

For more info please visit

http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=173424

Comment: Rater than just posting a link, can you please [edit] and explain what the OP has to change?

Comment: I have no "translate to english" option, i only have the useless "translate to italian" option

Comment: change chrome default language to english

Answer (score -1):

Update to [@Sergio Martinez de Cestafe](https://superuser.com/users/268153/sergio-martinez-de-cestafe) answer

Using chrome://translate-internals on Chrome Version 52 I set **Override Variations Country** to "**en**"

Tested on one site and clicking Translate in Chrome now translates to English rather than my local country language.

Comment: Does not work, it just says "Translate to italian" of whatever you had before.