# How to change default language for different source language in Google Chrome's translate function

Tags: google-chrome, language, browser-addons, translation, google-translate

By default, Google Chrome's embedded translate function will only default to translate webpages to user's webpage setting. Same for the translate option provided via right click manual

In the question "[Change default language in the google chrome translator bar](https://superuser.com/questions/376794/)", some methods and workarounds have been proposed to change the default translate language, including via "chrome://translate-internals" page, and also the official "Google Translate" add-on available in chrome webstore.

However, all these methods only allow the configuration of one single target language. I would like to set language-pair-specific-setting, as in translate most of the other languages into English, but then translate Chinese (Simplified) into Chinese (Traditional), and also translate Korean into Japanese, because they are additional direct translation pairs supported by Google Translate and would provide relatively higher quality translation result.

Is there any method to accomplish such setting configuration?